# How do databases update the schemas without re-writing them

Tags: database

I am working on a project and one thing that I need to do is update the file without re-writing it.
I was thinking about databases and that surely they are not re-writing entire files when a user updates it.
But I can't seem to find a good article, documentation on how does a database update files.
does anyone have a good source or maybe care to explain?

any help is appreciated.

Comment: [tag:mongodb] is a bit of a bad choice here, since it’s schemaless…

Comment: data is stored in documents so on one line update they don't update the whole document right?

Comment: You open up the file, seek a position within it using a byte offset, then overwrite x number of bytes in it. That's the basic logic behind not rewriting the entire file. The exact implementation is OS and programming language specific.

Comment: @Shadow That only works if the data you’re writing has the same length as the data you’re overwriting, otherwise you will either leave garbage or overwrite data coming after!

Comment: That's one way to do it, sure. You may also leave "pointers" ("data continues at offset xyz…"), or write all data in compact binary blocks and use a separate file which basically stores "document A consists of blocks 245-278, 370-380 and 1234-2012", and just rewrite that index file in its entirety… Many tricks that can be done here, and which one any given database uses depends on it and the storage engine in use.

Comment: I went for the blocks approach, I made a separate file that holds the original files key and a block field that holds the byte blocks from the file